# Регулярно падает MySQL

Tags: sql

У нас сайты на битрикс, и последнее время несколько раз в неделю по неизвестной причине падает сервер MySQL с ошибкой connection refused (400).
Память проверили - всё ок. Резервное копирование временно отключили - не помогло.
Вот что показывает error log:

```
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 7f16a35ae900 InnoDB: Error: page 506 log sequence number 4589647086
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188146.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-01-27 19:48:50 7f1627bf9700 InnoDB: Error: page 438 log sequence number 4587565709
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.45-86.1 started; log sequence number 4587188146
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139733116090112 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2022-01-27 19:48:50 7f16a352d700 InnoDB: Error: page 77 log sequence number 4627863109
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 7f16a352d700 InnoDB: Error: page 74 log sequence number 4627864719
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:48:50 139735206652160 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.43-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MariaDB Server
2022-01-27 19:49:05 7f16a34e2700 InnoDB: Error: page 17 log sequence number 4587803911
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:49:06 7f16a34e2700 InnoDB: Error: page 94 log sequence number 4589214364
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2022-01-27 19:49:07 7f16a34e2700 InnoDB: Error: page 116 log sequence number 4590438799
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188897.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

Скажите, что в такой ситуации сделать, чтобы выяснить причину сбоев?

Comment: для начала смотреть лог mysql (путь указан в конфиге в параметре log-error)

Comment: @Mike добавил логи в свой вопрос.

Comment: в логе вот прямо написано где что почитать по этой проблеме ... InnoDB: Error: page 94 log sequence number 4589214364
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4587188156.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Comment: @Mike но через force recovery мы каждый раз восстанавливаем работу сайта после сбоя. А в статье пишут об этом же. То есть это просто временное решение

Comment: Снести все файлы и восстановить данные из бэкапа не пробовали?